# Better to draw two times the same sprite or one double-sized sprite?

Tags: c, sfml

I'm working on a parallax background and I would like to know which method is the best to draw a scrolling background :

Should I write two sprites one just next to the second and update the position of both or write a single sprite with two times the same pic stick on each other ?

(I'm looking for the best perfs)

Thanks

Comment: Why not try both methods and compare the results?

Comment: Many reasons : I'm working on a school project and I'm limited in time and because I don't really see how to test it :)

Comment: Take the easiest to write option. See if it is fast enough, if it is, move on, if not, try the other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the best way to answer this is to test it yourself however there is this in the FAQ for SFML:

https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#graphics-xsprite

One of the fastest way to draw in SFML is to switch your implementation to use it's `VertexArray` as this is only 1 draw call to draw many objects.

SFML has an example how to use a VertexArray here:
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-vertex-array.php

A quick look at the way a sprite is drawn, a Sprite in SFML has 4 verts, each vert has to be transformed by the vertex shader in OpenGL.  So if you are drawing the same sprite you are transforming 8 vertex's, where if you double the size, you are drawing 4 verts.  The cost on the fragment shader should be relatively the same.

One last note, Get it working now optimize later.